# Is DFS supposed to check children for the goal state?

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

Is DFS (depth-first search) supposed to check all children of a given node for the goal state before moving on to the next node?

Answer (score 1):

Yes (except if the DFS stops in a child node of course). 
Demos:

- http://www.rci.rutgers.edu/~cfs/472_html/AI_SEARCH/SearchAnimations.html
- http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/combinatorica/animations/search.html
- http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/jawaa2/examples/DFS.html

[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question- The graphic does NOT check the child of each node for the goal state before moving to the next node.

It appears to move down the left most path until termination and then backtraces to move down the next left-most path. Which is how DFS works- I'm just wondering if DFS should check for the goal state in all children of any given node before moving down the left-most unvisited path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, either, but:

In a DFS, when you are at a node, you do a goal test.  If you are not at the goal, you move to the leftmost child, test it, etc.  Let's assume that leftmost child is not the goal and is a leaf.  Then you move back up to its parent and move to the second leftmost node, check it, etc.  Then the third leftmost child, etc.

You do not do something like "check all the children, *then* move to the leftmost child," if that's what you're asking.

In the animation above, you will see brief little question-marks as each node is lit up.  I believe those are meant to convey the goal tests as they happen.

Answer (score 0):

Depth first search means exactly that: run down the leftmost child nodes *first*. Only when a node has no children do you unwind your calls and try another child at a higher level. You can see this is the animation, the left node of the root does *not* check all the children first.

You can check all children first: this is called *breadth* first search. In the case of the animation Franck provided, this would cause both children of the root to be tested, and then descend down the left most child and check both those nodes and so on.

Remember that the test of a node for the goal state happens *after* reaching the node in the tree, but before expanding the node for children. (After all, if we found the goal, we are done).

Note, if you are looking for the *cheapest* (minimal depth) goal path (assuming multiple such paths are available) then breadth first is probably what you are looking for.